# How Do I move Vertices in The UV Editor?

Tags: uv, vertices, transforms

I would like to reposition parts of the mesh after I unwrapped it on the texture I imported, but I don't know how. I can scale and select them, but can I not move them? I'm not familiar with this new method of adding texture.[image]

Comment: Okay... I found an inconvenient way to do it, but I hope there is a better one. That little arrow in the upper right corner of the UV Editor opens to show X and Y adjustments which lets me move them.

Comment: Just use the move tool in the uv editor panel just like you do in the 3D viewport... The tools menu is hidden in the screenshot but you can open it by pressing T while the mouse cursor is hovering over the uv editor panel. Or you can click on the little arrow tab on the left side of the uv editor panel.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was hoping for and couldn't find. I didn't know T hid that.